# Image loop w/ UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uiimageview, uiimage

Im trying to set a loop of images as a background. Heres the code I have so far.

```
-(UIImageView *)loginBackround {

loginBackround = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
loginBackround.animationImages = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-0.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-1.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-2.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-3.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-4.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-5.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-6.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-7.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-8.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-9.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-10.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-11.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-12.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-13.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-14.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-15.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-16.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-17.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-18.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-19.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-20.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-21.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-22.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-23.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-24.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-25.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-26.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-27.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-28.gif"]];
loginBackround.animationDuration = 0.5;
loginBackround.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[loginBackround startAnimating];
return loginBackround;
```

}

backgroundArray returns (null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one out:

```
- (void)startupLoading:(UIView*)view
{
    NSArray *arr_img=@[@"tmp-0.gif",@"tmp-1.gif",@"tmp-2.gif"];
    NSMutableArray *images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i=0; i< arr_img.count ;i++)
    {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[arr_img objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    img_load=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((view.frame.size.width/2)-50.0, (view.frame.size.height/2)-50.0, 100, 100)];
    img_load.animationImages=images;
    img_load.animationDuration=2.0;
    [view addSubview:img_load];
    [img_load startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: You're an absolute genius. The only thing I had to edit was the Frame. The only issue is that the view is hiding the rest of my objects on IB. I tried bringing the individual button to the front by calling [self.view bringSubviewToFront: button]; but that does nothing. I also tried sending the picture view to the back in the same manner which works but then its no longer visible. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. The imageView was being hidden behind a second View when i sent it to the back. Looks great!